# String(contentsOfFile:encoding:) aborts with exit status 139

Tags: swift, file, heroku, file-io, swift3

I'm trying to call `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)` in my Swift 3.0.2 (happens with 3.0.1 too) server app on Heroku (which runs it on Ubuntu), but the function aborts the program. The following error is shown in `heroku logs`:

```
2016-12-26T01:59:01.304535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 139
```

There's no error message other than that. The file that I'm trying to read is located in the same directory tree as the source files of the app. Here's a functionally equivalent contraction of the actual code (at the top-level in `main.swift`):

```
let sqlDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file).deletingLastPathComponent().path + "/Models/SQL/"

do {
    print("reading")
    fflush(stdout)
    let a = try String(contentsOfFile: sqlDirectory + "createTables.sql", encoding: .utf8)
    print("done")
    fflush(stdout)
} catch {
    print("error")
    fflush(stdout)
}
```

The runtime value of `sqlDirectory` is `/tmp/build_514c5587b46ef976e60d4f039b4d048d/Sources/App/Models/SQL/` (the hash is different in each build). It crashes after printing `reading`. `done` or `error` is never printed. (The stdout flushes are there just for debugging to make sure everything is written to stdout. Removing them doesn't affect the crash.)

What's this about and how can I fix it?

<sub>I also reported this as a bug [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3490) because it seems this might be a bug.</sub>

Comment: Status 139 is `segmentation fault`(SIGSEGV).

Comment: `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)`  throws, do you call it in a do/try/catch context? How do you specify the file name and path? What  encoding are you passing to the call? I am not familiar with Heroku, but the location of the source files is probably not the current working directory of the process.

Comment: @MartinR Modified the question with the details.

Comment: @tuple_cat, why are you dismissing error value? Can you `catch let error` and printout error value instead of "error" string?

Comment: @user28434 That's what I'm doing in the actual code.

Comment: @tuple_cat, can you put error value in question then? If it gets into `catch` block, ofc.

Comment: @user28434 It doesn't get to the catch block at all, as explained in the question. The code crashes at the `String.init` call, and `print("error")` is never executed.

Comment: @tuple_cat, ok, missed that. Can you printout result of `sqlDirectory + "createTables.sql"`, you might have improper path to file. Maybe your `sqlDirectory` lacks separator slash.

Comment: @user28434 The value of `sqlDirectory` is in the question as well. Please read it before commenting.

Comment: @tuple_cat, then you're trying to open `"/tmp/build_514c5587b46ef976e60d4f039b4d048d/Sources/AppcreateTables.sql" file instead of ""/tmp/build_514c5587b46ef976e60d4f039b4d048d/Sources/App/createTables.sql"". You lack slash.

Comment: @user28434 Nope, there's a trailing slash in `sqlDirectory`. Besides, reading an invalid path should throw an error, not crash with a segfault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131513/discussion-between-user28434-and-tuple-cat).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the result of `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: sqlDirectory + "createTables.sql")` and it's `false`.

So that explains why `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)` crashes. Although it should throw an error instead of crashing. Here's the underlying bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1547, which seems to be caused by this bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-585.

I still have to find out why the path doesn't exist on Heroku. Maybe Heroku moves or deletes all source files after the build?